# How can I access web.config values from within a class attribute?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, cors, asp.net-web-api, custom-attributes

I have the following EnableCors attribute on a WebApi controller class:

```
[EnableCors(origins:"http://localhost:57280", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class PhysicalActivityController : ApiController
```

But I don't want that url hard-coded. I want to fetch it from web.config.

Something like this:

```
[EnableCors(origins: System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ModellingApiUrl"], headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class PhysicalActivityController2 : ApiController
```

The problem is that I can't access methods like that from within an attribute. The context of the code is not the same as being within an ordinary method. When I write the code as in the second example, Visual Studio highlights "AppSettings" in red, and gives the error "Cannot resolve symbol 'AppSettings'".

Any ideas on how I can achieve this? I tried writing a custom attribute that inherits from EnableCors, but sadly System.Web.Http.Cors.EnableCorsAttribute is a sealed class, so I can't inherit from it.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this in the end by a wholesale copy of the code for the EnableCors attribute, and then I modified it to fetch values from the config.

The problem is that the string which is passed into the attribute is an argument to its constructor, and needs to be a compile-time constant. Therefore I don't believe that what I wanted to do was possible - you have to edit the code behind the attribute.

My solution:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1019:DefineAccessorsForAttributeArguments", Justification = "Attribute arguments are accessible as collections.")]
public sealed class EnableCorsUsingConfigAttribute : Attribute, ICorsPolicyProvider
{        
    public EnableCorsUsingConfigAttribute(string configKeyForOrigins, string headers, string methods)
        : this(configKeyForOrigins, headers, methods, null)
    {
    }

    public EnableCorsUsingConfigAttribute(string configKeyForOrigins, string headers, string methods, string exposedHeaders)
    {
        string origins = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[configKeyForOrigins];
```

(the rest of the code is a direct copy of the EnableCors attribute)

Usage:

```
[EnableCorsUsingConfig(configKeyForOrigins: "ModellingApiClientUrls", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class PhysicalActivityController : ApiController
{
```

Comment: This sounds like it would solve my problem, but where would I find the rest of the CORS code for the new class?

Comment: Use Visual Studio to view the code for the existing EnableCors attribute. My method would be to temporarily add the attribute onto something, put the cursor into it, then hit F12 or Ctrl + B (depending on keyboard mapping), or right-click - "Go to implementation".

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ModellingApiUrl"].ToString();
```

use this code i hope this is useful to you

Comment: Sadly no, that doesn't work either. The problem is that you are in the middle of the attribute when you write this code - you are not in an ordinary code context. Therefore it seems you cannot call methods on system objects in the way you normally could. If you try doing it, you will see what I mean.

Comment: To clarify: When I write the code as in the second example above, Visual Studio highlights "AppSettings" in red, and gives the error "Cannot resolve symbol 'AppSettings'".

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add :

`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AllowedOriginsCors"].ToString();`

the external file :

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="AllowedOriginsCors" value="http://localhost:4200" />
  </appSettings>
```